# disable key press for a textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have text box which is generated in drupal expose filter.I have tried to disable typing in text box.but still textbox is not disabled.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init">
```

Comment: to disable use `$('#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: <input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init" disabled>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init">
```

Use preventDefault() instead of stopPropagation().

If you can edit the HTML itself, adding the property "disabled" disables the input completely.

Answer (score 0):

just add disabled

```html
<input disabled type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add readonly attribute inside the input type="text" as shown below :

```
<input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" 
name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" 
class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init" readonly="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init" disabled>
```

why cant you make it disable using disabled attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/co8dd2nx/

Or if you want to disable it with javascript, you have to execute it on load. Something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('1').disabled = true;
};
```